# Why some cases can be ignored when dealing with probability

Tags: probability

Simultaneously roll a blue die and a red die repeatedly until the values on the dice agree. Let X denote the number of rolls for which the dice total seven. Find the probability mass function of X.

The solution says we can ignore rolls in which the dice do not total seven and are not equal. I am wondering why we can do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that as a result of the fact that the probabilities associated with rolling a given amount are independent of the results of any previous rolls (i.e. the system is Markovian).

Consequently, you can ignore rolls that neither trigger the “end condition” (values are equal) nor alters the value of the random variable in question (no. of times the total equals seven), because the number of “null” rolls doesn’t affect the probabilities of either ending the rolls or rolling a net seven.